# Full screen background image on HomeScreen in React Native app iphone 11

Tags: ios, typescript, react-native

I'm currently trying to set a full background image on my login view on iphone 11

```
     const Background = styled.ImageBackground`

      padding:20px;
      justify-content:center;

      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      `
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            imageContainer: {
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'stretch'
            },
            image: {
              flex: 1
            }
          });
    
        return <SafeAreaView style={styles.imageContainer}><Background style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/images/background-cover.jpg')}>
            <CoverLogo width={100} height={100} color={Colors.White} />
    
            <Introduction loop={false}>
                <TextHeading text={`TestHeader`} />
                
            </Background>
        </SafeAreaView>
```

Currently what gets outputted:

[image]

I want the background to take over the white space. This issue seems to only occur in phone 11s

Comment: Try removing SafeAreaView

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Are you using `full screen` in Xcode settings?

Comment: @SaachiTech how do you do that?

Comment: You can find the option here `Project Target > General > Deployment Info`

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your SafeAreaView with image and make sure that the opacity of SafeAreaView is set to 0.

```
<ImageBackground
    source={imgsrc}
    style={{position: "absolute", height: "100%", width: "100%"}}>
    <SafeAreaView style={{opacity: 0}}>
       // place for your app components
    </SafeAreaView>
</ImageBackground>
```